scrapy tsv file download. how to convert file to parquet before upload to s3
I have a working scrapy project that downloads tsv files and saves them to s3.
I use a custom pipeline to save the original file names with dates.
I am wondering if it is possible to convert the tsv files to parquet before uploading them to s3. If so how would I do this in scrapy?
I should note that I am able to convert the files locally (last code block) but would like to do it inline before they are uploaded to s3.
This is what I have currently working....
##items
class DownfilesItem(scrapy.Item): 
    file_urls = scrapy.Field() 
    files = scrapy.Field() 
    original_file_name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()

##pipeline to save original file names with dates
class OriginalNameFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        test = request
        file_name_xml = request.url.split("=")[-1]
        file_name: str = file_name_xml.removesuffix('.tsv') + '_' + datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d") + '.' +  file_name_xml.split(".")[-1]
        return file_name

##in my scraper
def parse_all_items(self, response):
        all_urls = [bunch or urls]
        
        for url in all_urls:
            item = DownfilesItem()
            item['file_urls'] = [url]
            item['original_file_name'] = url.split("=")[-1] 
            yield item

##converting tsv to parquet locally 
parse_options = csv.ParseOptions(delimiter="\t")

for name in os.listdir(src_dir):
    localpath = os.path.join(src_dir, name)
    print(localpath)
    if ".tsv" in localpath:
        table = csv.read_csv(localpath, parse_options=parse_options)
        pq.write_table(table, localpath.replace('tsv', 'parquet'))


as I know scrapy uses pipeline to export to different files or other places (e.g. S3) - see Exporters and Feed Exports - so you can write own pipeline to export to parquet. You can get source code for CSV exporter and try to use it with parquet

CSV exporter is wrong direction. if you want to convert downloaded files then you may need to change FilePipeline - see source cod for file_downloaded. It seems it gets downloaded data as io.BytesIO and it send it to self.store which probably save it on disk. If you would use io.BytesIO to convert data to parquet and then it should save it as parquet. It may need also to change extension in `path. .

Other idea: after self.store.persist_file(path, ...) gets path and read from file, and save in new format

other idea: get class FSFilesStore and create own class with own persist_file() and convert data (in memory using BytesIO) before absolute_path.write_bytes()

you could also check how works ImagePipeline because (as I remember) it convert all images to JPG - so you may make something similar with your file. It seems it do it in convert_image and it also uses BytesIO to do it in memory.

Using the same example site as in the updated question, here is the spider:
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "parquet"
    start_urls = ["https://onlinetestcase.com/csv-file/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            if url.endswith('.csv'):
                url = response.urljoin(url)

                yield scrapy.http.Request(
                    url,
                    callback=self.parse_csv,
                    dont_filter=True
                )

    def parse_csv(self, response):
        yield {
            "url": response.url,
            # Convert CSV text into Data Frame.
            "data": pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text))
        }

It identifies the CSV links, then follows each link and pulls the data down, converting it into a Data Frame. The Data Frame is yielded along with the source URL.
The following pipeline then processes all of the resulting objects, converting the CSV filename to a Parquet filename and dumping the Data Frame.
import re
from collections import defaultdict


class ParquetPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.items = defaultdict(lambda: [])

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # Iterate over items, writing each to Parquet.
        #
        for name, df in self.items.items():
            df.to_parquet(name, index=False)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # Get CSV filename.
        csv = re.search("[^/]+$", item["url"]).group(0)
        # Create Parquet filename.
        parquet = re.sub("\.csv", ".parquet", csv)

        self.items[parquet] = item["data"]

⚠️ Note: For this example to work you will need to set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False in settings.py.

I don't have enough information to provide a complete working solution, but perhaps something along these lines would work?
import re
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd


class ParquetPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.items = defaultdict(lambda: [])

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # Iterate over pages, writing data for each to a parquet file.
        #
        for page, data in self.items.items():
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df.to_parquet(f"page-{page}.parquet", index=False)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # Extract page number from URL.
        #
        # ⚠️ You'd probably want to replace the page number with the file name here.
        #
        page = int(re.search(r"/page/(\d+)/", item["file_urls"]).group(1))

        self.items[page].append(dict(item))
        return item

I integrated this pipeline into the Scrapy crawler tutorial example for scraping quotes.
This is the general principle:

The spider navigates over multiple pages of quotes.
For each page the spider yields a series of items that have a file_urls field.
The pipeline processes each item, adding it to a dictionary. The dictionary is keyed with the page number, which maps to a list of items extracted for that page.
At completion the close_spider() method is called, which iterates over the key/value pairs in the dictionary, writing the data for each page to a separate file.

I'd suggest that you take a similar approach, but use the original file name rather than the page number to key the dictionary.
With this approach all of the data is stored in memory until the end of the crawl, when it is all written to file. This should be sufficient to get a working solution, however you'd probably want to find a way of shifting the data to disk earlier so that you don't run into memory constraints with big crawls.

i went through and updated the code. changing pages to filename. updated process item but it just saves the download links to a parquet file.. im hoping to convert the downloaded tsv file to a parquet before it gets uploaded to s3. maybe im missing something

Sorry, I misunderstood what you are attempting to do. I've added a separate answer that I think should do the job.

In your FilesPipeline you can add function
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

which is executed when file was downloaded - and then you may convert it.
(Doc: FilesPipeline.item_completed, Source Code: FilesPipeline.item_completed)
Something like this.
class OriginalNameFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    
    # ... code ...

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

        # filter results - to work only with correctly downloaded files
        results = [x for ok, x in results if ok]

        item['parquet'] = []

        # iterate over downloaded files
        for result in results:
            
            source_path = result['path']
            target_path = source_path.replace('.tsv', '.parquet')
            
            parse_options = csv.ParseOptions(delimiter="\t")
            table = csv.read_csv(source_path, parse_options=parse_options)
            pq.write_table(table, target_path)
            
            item['parquet'].append(target_path)

        return item


Full working code which I tested on some .csv on page https://onlinetestcase.com/csv-file/
This code doesn't need to create project.
You can put all code in one file and run it as python script.py.
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
import pandas as pd

#from contextlib import suppress
#from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://onlinetestcase.com/csv-file/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('>>> url:', response.url)

        for url in response.css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            if url.endswith('.csv'):
                print('>>> csv url:', url)
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                #yield {'file_urls': [url], 'other_folder': 'hello_world'}
                yield {'file_urls': [url]}


class ConvertFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    
    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

        #print('>>> results:', results)
        #print('>>> item:', item)
        #print('>>> info:', info)
        
        # filter results - code from original `item_completed()
        #with suppress(KeyError):
        #    ItemAdapter(item)[self.files_result_field] = [x for ok, x in results if ok]

        # filter results - to work only with correctly downloaded files
        results = [name for ok, name in results if ok]

        #item[self.files_result_field] = []  # it should create `item['files']`
        item['parquet'] = []

        # iterate over downloaded files
        for result in results:
            #print('>>> result:', result)
            
            source_path = result['path']
            target_path = source_path.replace('.csv', '.parquet')
            
            df = pd.read_csv(source_path)
            df.to_parquet(target_path)
            
            #result['parquet'] = target_path
            item['parquet'].append(target_path)

        #print('<<< item:', item)
        
        return item

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.ConvertFilesPipeline': 1}, # using Pipeline created in current file (needs __main___)
    'FILES_STORE': '.',  # this folder has to exist before downloading
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start() 


You can simply install scrapy-contrib-bigexporter to directly save to parquet from Scrapy: https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/scrapy-contrib-bigexporters
It supports parquet, orc and avro. It has a couple of configuration options that allow you to be flexible (e.g. automatic inference of schema, compression etc.).
See here also an example on how to use parquet: https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/scrapy-contrib-bigexporters/tree/main/examples/quotes_parquet
